# Calculate T Student Test for the next table in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I need calculate t value using (alpha)/2 and df for the next table:

https://www.fisterra.com/mbe/investiga/t_student/images/t_stud4.gif

test : t(n-1,alpha/2) and (gl = df)

I need you to return the following value:

```
t(0.025,9) = 2,262
```

What is the right way?

I just found the following form,

```
import scipy.stats as sts
sts.t.ppf(0.95,9) = 1.8331129
```

which is for alternating table:

http://image.slidesharecdn.com/tablat-student-120318105418-phpapp02/95/tabla-t-student-1-728.jpg?cb=1332086091

Comment: at the first sight, I guess you have to write `sts.t.ppf(0.975,9)` to get the right result

Comment: the link on the question is no longer working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
import scipy.stats

def t(alpha, gl):
    return scipy.stats.t.ppf(1-(alpha/2), gl)
```

You can test it with

```
print(t(0.05,9))
```

The result will be `2.262`

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.